# Enter "thin space" easily in Rmarkdown's for rendering LaTeX

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to insert a [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space) (~0.16em) in an Rmd file to be rendered in LaTeX.

An easy to type way for a thin space in LaTeX is "\,". However, this symbol appears not be recognized by RMarkdown, or not translated to correct LaTeX. I've tried different version:

"e.\, g."
"e.\\,g."
"e.\\, g."
"e.\\\, g."
"e.\\\\, g."
(I've skipped the blank before "g.", too.)

But I could not get a thin space between "e" and "g".

My TeXLife Version is from 2017 (Mac); RMarkdown and RStudio are uptodate.

**EDIT**: I don't want to use "\thinspace" as this is too much to type.

Comment: better at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. ask a moderator to move it -so you- do not crosspost. (edit)

Comment: I dont't think it is a TeX issue. I think it's a rmarkdown issue. I did not post at other places.

Comment: @SebastianSauer: See [this github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2025).